# Trouble with counting and highlights

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create two functions. One uses two arguments, a filename, and a keyword. It needs to highlight the word and return the highlighted word or words with the line number.

The second function counts the number of times a specific word occurs in a file. Once again this one uses two arguments a filename and a keyword.

This one is called highlight. It needs to look at each line, find the keyword, then returns the line number with the keyword highlighted bracketed by '-->' on the left and '<--" on the right.

```
def highlight(filename, keyword):
    inpt = open(filename, "r")
    for line in inpt:
        if re.match(keyword, line):
            print ('-->',line,'<--')
```

This function uses a filename and keyword and counts the number of times a specific word occurs in a file, then returns the count.

```
def count_word(filename, keyword):
    fname = (filename)
    word= (keyword)
    count = 0
    with open(fname, 'r') as in_file:
        for line in in_file:
            words = line.split()
            for i in words:
                if(i==word):
                    count=count+1
                print (count)
```

Am I going in completely the wrong direction? Am I close at all?

The text file reads:

```
I heart Rocket!
Rocket, Rocket, Rocket.
Don't say it.
Rocket, Rocket, Rocket!





Rocket!!!
```

Right now I am getting:

```
highlight:
printed:
--> Rocket, Rocket, Rocket.
 <--
--> Rocket, Rocket, Rocket!
 <--
--> Rocket!!!
 <--

expected:
1:   I heart -->Rocket<--!
2:   -->Rocket<--, -->Rocket<--, -->Rocket<--.
4:   -->Rocket<--, -->Rocket<--, -->Rocket<--!
10:  -->Rocket<--!!!


count_word:

printed:
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0

expected:
8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you iterate lines from a file, each line ends with a newline `'\n'`.

If you prepend `'-->'` and append `'<--'`, the `'<--'` is added *after* the newline character. You could change your code, remove the \n and add <-- .. but it can be done far easier:

- replace text with [str.replace("replace what","replace with what")](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)
- [enumerate (iterable, start)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) your lines
- use [f-string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals)
- count using [str.count()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count)

*Create file:*

```
with open("k.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("""I heart Rocket!
Rocket, Rocket, Rocket.
Don't say it.
Rocket, Rocket, Rocket!





Rocket!!!""")
```

*Process file:*

```
with open("k.txt") as f:

    # read all text
    text = f.read()

    # replace Rocket with -->Rocket<-- and store as text2
    text2 = text.replace("Rocket","-->Rocket<--")

    # split at \n, enumerate result starting at 1, remove any line 
    # that does not contain Rocket, join with \n
    text3 = text2.split("\n")
    text4 = [f"{row:2d} {x}" for row,x in enumerate(text3,1) if "Rocket" in x]
    text5 = "\n".join(text4)

    # Count rockets and print replaced text
    print(text.count("Rocket")) 
    print(text3)
    print(text4)
    print(text5)
```

Output:

```
# the rocket count
8  

# text3: all lines
['I heart -->Rocket<--!', '-->Rocket<--, -->Rocket<--, -->Rocket<--.', "Don't say it.", 
'-->Rocket<--, -->Rocket<--, -->Rocket<--!', '', '', '', '', '', '-->Rocket<--!!!']

# text4: with enumeration of line number 
[' 1 I heart -->Rocket<--!', ' 2 -->Rocket<--, -->Rocket<--, -->Rocket<--.', 
 ' 4 -->Rocket<--, -->Rocket<--, -->Rocket<--!', '10 -->Rocket<--!!!']

 # joined together again 
 1 I heart -->Rocket<--!
 2 -->Rocket<--, -->Rocket<--, -->Rocket<--.
 4 -->Rocket<--, -->Rocket<--, -->Rocket<--!
10 -->Rocket<--!!!
```

---

If you want to confuse yourself you can do it as 4-liner:

```
with open("k.txt") as f:
    text = "\n".join( 
        [f"{row:2d} {x}" for row,x 
         in enumerate( f.read().replace("Rocket","-->Rocket<--").split("\n"),1) 
         if "Rocket" in x])
    print(text.count("Rocket")) 
    print(text)
```

Comment: That works well, thank you, but I am still having the issue of it labeling the line number for the highlight portion. The output should list the line number at the beginning example: 1:     -->Rocket<--

Comment: @j.a.martin use enumerate to enumerate the lines before excluding what does not match - see edit.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it. I hope to be able to answer the questions sometime in the future.